# jsoup parsing, selecting unattributed HTML

Tags: jquery, html, dom, jquery-selectors, jsoup

*Preamble:*

My mobile carrier is kind enough to provide a homepage that allows their customers to keep track of their dataplan (bandwidth used, maximum bandwidth, etc). 
I'd like to create an (Android) App for that, using jsoup for the parsing.

*The problem:*

Sadly, said webservice has no APIs and the DOM structure is, well, dodgy at best.

```
<div class="barTextBelow color_default">
    <span class="colored">33,84 MB</span> von 500 MB verbraucht
</div>
```

`div.barTextBelow > span` isolates the amount of bandwidth used, including the unit: 
`33,84 MB`

I still need to query the maximum bandwidth, behind the `<span>`-Tag.
Is it possible to query `von 500 MB verbraucht` or even `500 MB` without resorting to regex or in-app text manipulation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it like here, if you use jQuery. first get the whole div content, then split it by its first part (the span content) into array in which 1-st element will be second part of the string

```
var wholeText = $('div.barTextBelow').text().split($('div.barTextBelow span').text())[1]; 
var trafficAmount = wholeText.replace(/[^\d]/gi,''); //500
```